# Splitting polygons based on points density

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I have a geojson file with polygons representing administrative regions.

I also have a shapefile from which I can extract a list of points of interest (schools).

I can iterate over this list of points, and for each point, check what polygon it falls within, and assign it to that polygon.

I then want to split each polygon into two, with the size of each child polygon inversely proportional to the number of points falling within that child polygon.

For example, I have polygon `A`, which contains 5 points. The area of this polygon is 5 square kilometers.

I want to split this polygon into two smaller polygons `B` and `C`, such that `B` will have a size of 2 square kilometers and contain 3 points, and `C` a size of 3 square kilometers.

Once I'm able to do this, I think I should be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do: I ultimately want to split up each polygon, representing an administrative region, into many smaller polygons/administrative regions.

The idea is that denser areas will have more administrative regions compared to less dense ones.

An analogy I'd give is: if I have polygons representing counties, and points representing schools, I want to divide each county into zones such that each zone has roughly roughly 10 schools. Which means that denser areas will have more/smaller zones.

If I'm able to split a polygon into two with the size of each child polygon inversely proportional to points assigned to it, I think I can recursively keep splitting polygons until I get to a specific minimum number of points per child polygon.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end each new polygon should contain 10 points (schools)? Or is there a limit to the boundary polygon size?

For splitting a polygon in smaller regions a voronoi method is often used. See [geovoronoi](https://pypi.org/project/geovoronoi/). This does result in irregular shapes. If regular shapes are needed you could create an empty grid first.

I think the challenge is defining when points should be clustered or not. Is this based on distance, density, can new boundaries be cross county? This could be done by using a [nearest neighbour](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2017/lessons/L3/nearest-neighbour.html) approach or using heatmaps maybe?   A heatmap approach would have to use quite a bit of extra coding and raster/vector conversion.

You could use a nearest neighbour approach first. And cluster points that are closest to each other in groups of 10. And assigning the clusters of 10 with the same ID. Next create a voronoi using all points. Then the resulting voronoi can be dissolved on the ID you created earlier. Now you have a layer where each polygon contains 10 points.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that all polygons contain roughly an equal number of points in the end. Which means that polygons in sparsely populated areas will be much larger.

New boundaries can't be cross county.

I'm looking at nearest neighbour and geovoronoi. Does sound like what I need. Will get back on what I come up with.

Meanwhile, I could also probably find the centroid of each cluster and create a voronoi off all centroids?

Thanks for the response. Great pointers.

Comment: Tried splitting my comment into multiple lines for readability, looks like this isn't possible...

Comment: Yes. Creating a centroid for the point clusters and basing the voronoi on that sounds like a good idea! Probably faster to. I'm curious to know if your method work. Hope you'll let us know.